# How to integrate Siri with an iOS app to allow voice search

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

How can I integrate Siri with a custom iOS app to allow users to search for keywords using their voices? For example the user speaks a keyword and activate the app to search for the result. Or searching specific information with a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two main ways to interact with SiriKit:

1. `NSUserActivity`, a basic action in your app.
2. `INIntent`, allows you to interact with Siri.

You have to choose which one fits you purpose. If you need user input (like a search term) from Siri you probably want to use an `INIntent` (available in iOS 13+) which then completes with a userActivity with the data you need. That should call the `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` function in your AppDelegate.

The user can choose to add those features to his SiriShortcuts app himself. You can add a `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` in your app to get the users attention to that feature.